# .NET Routing Actual URL

Tags: .net, routes, webforms

I'm using Routing with .NET web forms. (.NET 4.0)

How can the page find out what the actual URL is?

For example, at the following URL:

/routing/friendly-url/

I want the page to print out:

/folder/mypage.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Page.AppRelativeVirtualPath`.

Example:

```
<body>
  Path to ASPX: <%= Page.AppRelativeVirtualPath %>
</body>
```